# How to solve ESLint typedef error for importing lazy modules into routing module Angular?

Tags: angular, eslint

I'm importing lazy loading modules into my routing modules as it is shown in Angular tutorial. But ESLint doesn't like that I don't mention type annotation for it.

How is it possible to solve this issue whithout setting ESLint to ignore this rule?

```
  {
    path: 'user',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./user/user.module').then(
            (m) => m.UserModule,
          ),
      },
    ],
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do type annotation several ways like this:

Simple, not preferred

```
loadChildren: () =>
  import('./user/user.module').then(
    (m: Params) => m.UserModule,
  ),
```

More precise:

```
loadChildren: () =>
      import('./user/user.module').then(
        (m: typeof import('./user/user.module')) => m.UserModule,
      ),
```

Even more precise:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(
    (m: { UserModule: Type<UserModule> }) => m.UserModule,
),
```

Comment: I've just checked this solution one more time and I have a question -  for the third option I have to import module's class to the app.routing.ts file.

import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

It doesn't ruin the idea of lazy loaded modules?

Comment: Sure, it's ok and only refers to a type on compile time.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
loadChildren: async () => (await import('./user/user.module')).UserModule,
```